# Javascript button style opacity not changing properly

Tags: javascript, css, html

The button's opacity instantly changes to 0.9 instead of waiting 500 milliseconds before every 0.1 increment.

**Notes** : I have put this in a window load handler in my code, all elements have been loaded just fine and the loop is being executed. But why isn't it giving it a 500 milliseconds break? It just instantly turns to 0.9.

```
var interval = window.setInterval(login(),500);
var button=document.getElementById("login_btn");
var opacity = 0.1;
function login(){
    if(opacity >= 0.9){
        window.clearInterval(interval);
    }else{
        button.style.opacity=opacity;
        opacity+=0.1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument of `setInterval` needs to be a function.

You are passing it the *return value* (which is `undefined`) of calling `login`, so `login` is being called immediately to determine what that return value is.

Remove the `()`.

Comment: Umm..I did put it in a function and tried it, the loop doesn't even execute :S

Comment: @TalhaTanveer — Define "put it in a function", because that sounds like you've done something a lot more complicated then what I suggested.

Comment: Well, that is rather more complex then I suggested, and it adds a pile of code which depends on all sorts of things you aren't sharing. The code in the question, however, [just works if you make the change I suggested](http://jsbin.com/cafokijo/1/edit?html,output).

Comment: I'd use [transitions](http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/css-transitions) instead of JS animation though.